# Duvida como recuperar dados utilizando axios react-native

Tags: react-native, axios

Fala galera,

To iniciando ainda em react-native e estou fazendo um teste conectando a um webservice:

```
consultar(){
    var ret = '';

    ret = axios.get('http://192.168.0.142:8080/rest/clientes?cpf=05092845406').then( response => { console.log(response); })
    .catch( ()=> {console.log('Erro:');} );

    console.log(ret);  
    this.setState = {
      textoBusca: 'Pesquisou',
    };

    Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  ret.status ,
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
)

  }
```

o data desse get é um array de 1 linha e n colunas.